# Trying to run my first cron task, it's a executable shell file but cron does nothing but create an empty log file

Tags: linux, unix, cron, task

Heres the update.sh, it just runs updates on the system:

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo apt update 
sudo apt-get upgrade 
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

And here's the crontab command:

```
28 10 * * * user sh /home/user/Documents/Bash/update.sh& >>/tmp/mycommand.log
```

What it's currently doing is simply creating an empty mycommand.log file in the tmp folder, and not running the shell. What a'm I doing wrong, is it a permission issue because I have root access disabled?

Comment: What do you see in the cron logs?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cron/info . Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `&` from the end of your call, it's probably what's affecting the stream and unnecessary

Can the user read this and do they have permission to read+execute it?

- You can try a specific user with `sudo -u user update.sh`
- You can set executable bits for the script script `chmod 774 update.sh`